# Feedback on Migrating Questions

Tags: discussion, migration

This is a quick note on point totals when a recent question was migrated.   Here's the link:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/8164/revisions

During the migration, my total dropped 175 points in Cross Validated, and rose 60 points in Stackoverflow.   I'm not a point-hound, so it's not a problem.    However, in case someone is keeping track of this stuff, I thought I'd let you know.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No question.  Just feedback.

Comment: It belongs in chat, then, or as a flag to moderators in case you want some kind of action.  The point differential will be due to many things; the most significant would be that many CV upvoters might not have SO accounts and therefore their votes would not be counted on SO.

Comment: A possible question in this is whether the total point changes should be a wash. That is, if you lost 175 here, then you should gain 175 there, or if you gained 60 there, you should only lose 60 here.

Comment: This is expected; reputation is not shared across sites.  When a question is migrated, you don't lose your reputation.  However, when a question is *deleted*, then you absolutely lose your rep (assuming it's not from something really old).  That said, I'm not sure why the migrated question was deleted, as the system cleans these up automatically after a month or so IIRC.